# Having trouble explaining why the coordinating conjunction for this sentence is "or", not "and". Please help?

Tags: coordinating-conjunctions

My student's sentence:
Getting married before graduating from university is not a shrewd and sensible choice.

I've corrected their choice of coordinating conjunction "and" to "or" [i.e. Getting married before graduating from university is not a shrewd or sensible choice.] but I'm having trouble explaining my instinctual decision. I wonder if it has anything to do with the word "not" and how it might be drawn parallel in usage to the correlative conjunctions "neither... nor"? Or is it because *shrewd* and *sensible* are conditions that don't have to be simultaneously applied to the situation?

I would appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this question as I am properly discombobulated!

Answer (score 1):

Very strictly speaking that should be *… neither a shrewd nor a sensible choice.*

Failing that yes, *… not a shrewd or sensible choice.*

It’s both about usage parallel to *neither... nor* and because *shrewd* and *sensible* don't have to be applied simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

May be we can look at this sentence in different forms:

> "... is not a [shrewd and sensible] choice."

'Shrewd and sensible' are two adjectives that modify the noun 'choice' at the same time. The choice cannot be shrewd but not sensible or vice versa.

> "... is  [not a shrewd (choice) ], [nor a sensible choice]."

~ there are two relative clauses

> "... is not a [shrewd] or [sensible] choice."

'Shrewd and sensible' are two adjectives that can modify the noun 'choice' independently. The choice can be shrewd but not sensible; or sensible but not shrewd.